# How to run PM2 in a distroless image

Tags: pm2, distroless

I want to run node application with pm2 in distroless image.
As it do not have any shell inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this docker file for reference, for pm2 shell `/bin/sh` is required so we are manually copying all the required package from above image.
After passing the absolute path in CMD or ENTRYPOINT it will work fine.

```
FROM node AS build-env

ADD . /app

RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --omit=dev

RUN npm --loglevel info install pm2 -g

RUN ls -a

RUN pm2 --version

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:12

COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/ /usr/local

COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/ /usr/local

COPY --from=build-env /usr/sbin/ /usr/sbin

COPY --from=build-env /usr/share/ /usr/share/

COPY --from=build-env /usr/src/ /usr/src/

COPY --from=build-env /usr/bin/ /usr/bin/

COPY --from=build-env /bin/ /bin/

COPY --from=build-env /app /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js","hello_express.js"]
```